# View not found error on Laravel deployment to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

Have been at this for a while and nothing makes any sense whatsoever. Deploying Laravel 5 application to Heroku. And I'm getting this a view not found error. Whats weird is that it seems Laravel is looking for the view in a non existant folder namely heres the error:

```
 (1/1) InvalidArgumentException

View [site.home] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php (line 137)
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('site.home', array('/tmp/build_2069bb9b168e1f24aa9a231cfa30b0d9/resources/views'))in FileViewFinder.php (line 79)
at FileViewFinder->find('site.home')in Factory.php (line 128)
```

Heroku deploys the application to the `/app` folder but for some odd reason Laravel looks for the views in this non existant `/tmp/build_2069bb9b168e1f24aa9a231cfa30b0d9/` folder. I noticed that this folder was for some reason mentioned in the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. I did a number of `php artisan config:cache` and while that did fix the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file, I'm still getting this error.

Tried to clear cache, config - nothing is working - error doesn't budge. Where is that folder to start with - even checked the `/tmp` folder, nothing in there. Adding even a symbolic link doesnt help at all.

Comment: Did you try in other browser or by clearing browser's cache/cookies ?

Comment: Yes - everything - clear browsers cache, opened in a new browser - its haunted by this non existant folder /tmp/build_2069bb9b168e1f24aa9a231cfa30b0d9

Comment: Did you also delete `storage/framework/cache`,`storage/framework/sessions` and `storage/framework/views`

Comment: Those folders are already empty - I deleted them entirely - and still its the same error.. this is definitely something to do with configuring heroku here...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I'm experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy appliccation on Laravel you must know that the environment should be prepared. First of all, check few points and see the result:

1. Clear Cache in storage folder (especially view cache - simply remove view cache files - `storage/framework/views`)
2. Clear cache of config, routing and view by artisan commands:

   `php artisan view:clear`

   ```
   php artisan route:cache

   php artisan config:cache
   ```
3. Sometimes it is good to generate new application key:

   `php artisan key:generate`
4. If that things do not work, maybe you should check server configuration. Its long topic, but give please feedback how about this problem

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but that didnt work - I think its because on heroku the .env file has been uploaded and everything is stored as a system variable or so. Still doesnt explain why the wrong non existant folder is being accessed like that.

Comment: Doesnt make any difference - the tmp folder is off limits and heroku doesn't allow me to do a sudo there. I even went as far as creating a symbolic link - but no good. Nothing works at all here..

Comment: i did my best my friend

Comment: Thanks - pretty much quit and moved to a basic server

Comment: did my solutions help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for hours I was amazed how this was clearly a cache issue and I couldn't manage to fix it.
But then I found the answer based on a suggestion someone gave me here: [Heroku - View Not Found - FileFinderView InvalidArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555023/heroku-view-not-found-filefinderview-invalidargumentexception/61555724#comment108884604_61555023)

So I ran:

```
php artisan optmize:clear
```

And everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem.

Previous to this, I had a similar problem with a sessions file not being found. It turned out I had to create a new redis database and the driver type from 'file'.

So now both my SESSION_DRIVER and CACHE_DRIVER are redis. I suspect this problem that I'm having with the Views is something similar.

I see no help anywhere though...