# Heroku - View Not Found - FileFinderView InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

This is consuming the last 2 days of my life. Locally everything is working fine but when my code is deployed to Heroku, Laravel can't find the `index` view. It's my understanding this is some caching issue, so I have tried most of Artisan's commands to clean the cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

This is my route, I'm serving a SPA:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@main')->where('any', '.*');
```

And this is the stack trace on my view:
[image]

I have cleaned the `bootstrap/cache` folder and honestly I'm out of ideas. Does someone have a light on this one? Thanks

Comment: the best command to clear everything: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: I can't believe this worked. I have tried `php artisan optimize` before and it didn't work. Please @ChristopheHubert add an answer and I will gladly accept it o//

Comment: I'm glad it helped, answer added 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the all around cache clearing command :

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: tried that too still same error view not found

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to the same issue:

The issue itself seems to be caused by the official **php buildpack**, which does `php artisan optimize` at the end of the build process ***inside*** the build environment (aside from other things it clears and recreates the configuration cache). This causes the build directory `/tmp/build_xxxxxxxx/` to be saved into the configuration cache.

The solution is to run `php artisan config:clear`, but it won't take effect on the already built and running app because of how heroku works: when you access their shell you perform operations on the filesystem that's generated from a project build and is destroyed as soon as you exit the shell. The operations you perform on files in that shell don't effect the running app instances. `php artisan config:clear` must be ran at the end of the build process.

One way to do this is the [gerardbalaoro/laravel](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/gerardbalaoro/heroku-buildpack-laravel) buildpack which allows adding custom hooks after the build process. Keep in mind that it also does `php artisan views:clear` after the build while the official **php buildpack** doesn't. Using it and adding `LARAVEL_COMMANDS='php artisan config:clear'` to heroku config solved the issue for me.

tl;dr:

```
heroku buildpacks:set gerardbalaoro/laravel
heroku config:set LARAVEL_COMMANDS='php artisan config:clear'
git commit --allow-empty -m 'force rebuild'
git push heroku master
```

Comment: heroku push failed after applying these commands